# Calculation of pafaffian matrix form from spin-spin correlation function in free fermions theory

Tags: statistical-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, correlation-functions

I want to calculate the following correlation functions

\begin{equation}
\langle\sigma^{x}_{\ell}\sigma^{x}_{m} \rangle=\langle B_{\ell}A_{\ell+1}B_{\ell+1}\ldots A_{m-1}B_{m-1}A_{m}\rangle
\end{equation}
where $A_{\ell}$ and $B_{m}$ are fermionic operators. This can be expressed as the pafaffian matrix given in this attached image. [image: pafaffian]

I want to understand how does the form of the pafaffian is constructed from the correlation function. The paper link is shared here [enter link description here](https://journals.aps.org/pra/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevA.3.786)

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.